# Backbone.js: Binding an array of collection to a function

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have an array of collections (coll_array). All collections are bound to same function (process_coll) on all events. That means, any change to any of collection in the array results in execution of same function. My problem is how do I identify the collection on which the event took place. If I could pass arguments to the target function I could pass the identity of the collection but as far as I know there is no way to do it in Backbone events.

```
initialize: function(){
    _(this).bindAll('process_coll');
    coll_array ; //array of collections 
    for(var i=0;i<coll_array.length;i++)
        coll_array[i].bind('all', this.process_coll);
        coll_array[i].fetch();
}

process_coll: function(){
    //some code here 
    //how do I get the specific collection which resulted in execution of this function?
}
```

Comment: _(this).bindAll('process_coll') doesn't look elegant to me. Maybe you need a different design? See http://backbonejs.org/#Events-trigger. You can pass arguments when triggering events.

Comment: The collection will be passed to the handler in the argument list. Of course, the argument order depends on the event so you can either bind to the individual events separately (as Paul notes below) or you can try to parse `arguments` to find the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off listening for [specific events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog).

```
initialize: function(){
    coll_array ; //array of collections 
    for(var i=0;i<coll_array.length;i++)
        coll_array[i].bind('reset', this.reset_coll);
        coll_array[i].bind('add', this.add_coll);
        coll_array[i].bind('remove', this.remove_coll);
        coll_array[i].fetch();
}

reset_coll: function(collection, options){
    // collection argument is the one you want
}
add_coll: function(model, collection, options){
    // collection argument is the one you want
}

remove_coll: function(model, collection, options){
    // collection argument is the one you want
}
```