# Backbone.js: Get collection on which event occurred inside callback

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have multiple collections bound to the same callback. I need a way identify the collection on which the event actually occurred. But, I can't pass arguments to the callback in backbone.js. Is there a way out?

Comment: All events are passed some relevant arguments: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-catalog .

Comment: What callback or trigger? Take a peek at the backbone code. It's very approachable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone.js: Binding an array of collection to a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931901/backbone-js-binding-an-array-of-collection-to-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

In Backbone collection event handlers `this` is always set to the collection on which the event was triggered:

```
function eventHandler(){
    console.log(this); // this refers to either collection1 or collection2, depending on where the event was triggered
};
collection1.on("sth", eventHandler);
collection2.on("sth", eventHandler);
```